# Using ffmpeg on RTOS

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to capture video and audio from a webcam and stream it wirelessly through a software defined radio. Essentially, I need to packetize the video stream so that it is suitable for the transport layer implemented in INEGRITY OS running on an ARM processor. While I am able to capture the video and transmit it wirelessly, on the receiving end, when I try to view the video using ffplay, the quality is very bad. Ugly green patches and video tearing. Do pardon my ignorance but ffmpeg is not my forte. This is how I am sending the video :

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -crf 23 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -acodec libmp3lame -b 600k -flush_packets 0 -f mpegts udp://192.9.200.254:8000?pkt_size=1128
```

On the receiver end, I run ffplay using the following command :

```
ffplay udp://192.9.200.69:8000
```

Importantly, the video from the USB camera is sent over ethernet to an ARM processor running INTEGRITY RTOS. The transport layer of the Software Defined Radio is implemented in the RTOS. This is where the video data is multiplexed with other application data being transmitted through the SDR and hence a stringent requirement on the packet size (1128 bytes). From the ARM processor, the data packet is sent on to a DSP where the network and DLL layer are implemented and finally on to a FPGA where the PHY layer is implemented.

Apart from using ffplay, I have also tried mplayer, however, the video output is equally bad.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would do at least the following: (1) measure the packet error rate over the radio link and (2) try pre-defined video clips with different bit rates over the same link. These measures should give a lot of food for thought.

Comment: Hey Mike, I have a separate application for measuring BER and PER, but right now I have connected the two radios back to back, so no wireless transmission. I have also tried different bit rates ranging from 256 kbps upto a few Mbps. The output remains the same. From the log on ffplay/mplayer, I see a lot of "MV errors". Not the foggiest what that is.

Comment: If ffmpeg writes the video stream to a file instead of the UDP stream, can ffplay show such a stream with acceptable quality? Would be useful to establish if the problem is caused by transmission errors or not...

Comment: It's the same for a file too. So this implies transmission errors?

Comment: Sorry, the previous question probably was not stated clearly enough. If ffmpeg had recorded a video clip from the USB camera to an h.264 file on some flash drive, this file was copied to the receiver, played with ffplay and the quality is bad, then the problem has nothing to do with transmission errors and something is wrong with the encoding process. If the playback quality is OK, then transmission is to blame.

Comment: The quality is fine. So it's definitely the transmission. But is there anything I can do with ffplay to make it more tolerant to delays and losses, though I don't think any packet loss is occurring.

Comment: When RTSP over UDP is used as a transport stream, there is a parameter `reorder_queue_size` available: _Set number of packets to buffer for handling of reordered packets. When receiving data over UDP, the demuxer tries to reorder received packets (since they may arrive out of order, or packets may get lost totally)._ There seem to be no such option for UDP without RTSP.

Comment: Cool. Will try that. Can you specify pkt size when using RTSP?

Comment: Setting `pkt_size` should help. This is an RTP option, but RTSP uses RTP (over UDP in our case) for transport. BTW, there is another RTSP option `max_delay` (in microseconds), which defines the max time to wait for missing or reordered packets. As you've probably seen, ffmpeg documentation has an example `ffplay -max_delay 500000 -rtsp_transport udp rtsp://server/video.mp4`.